# How to figure out the target of a PDF outline that has only an SE dictionary

Tags: pdf

The PDF reference (12.3.3, Table 153) says that an outline will either have a Dest dictionary, an A dictionary, or an SE dictionary (with an optional Dest dictionary). I have a document with outlines that only have the SE dictionary. The reference directs me to the Structure Hierarchy (14.7.2), and this is where I've become lost. Structure items may have Pg dictionaries, but mine don't (and neither do the parents, on a recursive traversal). So I need to figure out the page number, offset in page and zoom (if applicable) from the SE dictionary. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure tree has a root node that is a bit special. It contains a few entries that the rest of the nodes do not have. There is one entry called **ParentTree** that is used for locating structure elements that correspond to pages, annotations and XForms. See *14.7.2 Structure Hierarchy* and *14.7.4.4 Finding Structure Elements from Content Items*.

The references between pages and structure elements go both ways, you are supposed to have the Pg entry in one structure element or one of its recursive parents (as far as I know if this is not the case the file can be considered as corrupt), and you *will* have an entry called StructParents in the page dictionary that contains the index that corresponds to that page in the ParentTree structure.

If the StructParents entry is missing inside the page dictionaries and the structure tree is present, then the file is most likely corrupt. With "corrupt" I mean that the information it contains is not consistent, coherent etc.

There are two ways of using this information then. If you have a reference to a structure element, you should be able to find the page it refers to by using the Pg entry. If you have a reference to a page, you should be able to use its corresponding structure element by using the ParentTree structure. Both directions are supposed to be present in the file for the information to be consistent.

Comment: According to the example in 14.7.6, not all structure elements must be present in the ParentTree (301 isn't). And 301 doesn't have the Pg entry. However, at least one child of such element does have a Pg entry (this is also true of my test document). Can I rely on this - and set the outline's target to the page of the first child in its SE entry that has a Pg entry?

Comment: I parted from the assumption that there is some marked content on the page referred, in such case the page must be in the ParentTree. Anyway I think it is not safe to take the first child that contains a Pg entry, since there might be other children nodes with other values in that entry.

Comment: OK, but in the example, 301 is not in the ParentTree, and neither it nor its parent have a Pg entry. If an outline points to it via an SE entry, what should happen?

Comment: Interesting... It seems it is safe to do what you said after all (use the first child with a Pg entry). Although it is not clear in the spec, I know that the order of items in the K arrays do matter, and the object 301 in the sample is a "chapter" (which is likely to have more than one page), so it kind of make sense to do as you said.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It would be nice if I could get the page number from a page object in O(1), but at least it works now :-)